# Rewriting an explicit formula as an recursive formula

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following series: $x_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$ and I'm trying to rewrite it as a recursive formula. I wrote the first 5 elements: $1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 5/6$ however I fail to find the recursive formula.

Could you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a recursive formula that does not include $n$ in its equation, here is one

Eq-1. 
$$x_{n} = \frac{n}{n+1} \to n = \frac{x_n}{1-x_n}$$
Eq-2.
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{n+2-1}{n+2} \to x_{n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{n+2} $$

Then you can replace $n$ in Eq-2, by $n$ in Eq-1

$$x_{n+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{\frac{x_n}{1-x_n}+2}$$ and $x_0 = 0.5$

And I leave the simplification for whoever is interested!

Edit:
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2-x_n}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are at least a couple of things you can do.  You can subtract $x_n$ from $x_{n+1}$, for example.

$$
\begin{align}x_{n+1}-x_n &= \frac{n+1}{n+2}-\frac n{n+1}=\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}\\
x_{n+1}&=x_n+\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align}
$$
You can get a different recursive formula if you divide $x_{n+1}$ by $x_n$.  Try it.

Comment: Of course there are many solutions to the problem.

Comment: @Babydesta Sure, I was just pointing out what I think are the most obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For $n\in \Bbb N$:
$$x_n={n\over n+1}\iff n={1\over 1-x_n}-1$$